# How do you keep a priority queue of pairs that's ordered by the second element?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose we have a priority queue such as:

```
priority_queue<pair<int, int> > pQ;
```

and we want pQ to be ordered so that the pair with the smallest second element is always first. Is there a simple way to accomplish this using C++11? It would be ideal if I had an elegant solution such as one that uses lambda functions. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You need to instantiate it with a custom comparison function, for example (namespace `std` assumed):

```
auto cmp = [](const pair<int, int>& lhs, const pair<int, int>& rhs)
{
  return lhs.second < rhs.second;
};

priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, decltype(cmp)> pQ(cmp);
```

Comment: Can you describe how to use this?

Comment: @BobJonas Ehm, just use it?

Comment: How do I push things onto the queue?

Comment: @BobJonas Just like you normally would.

Comment: Oh. I was using the un-edited version before and it wasn't compiling. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. `std::priority_queue` has a templated `Compare` functor that is used for sorting. You can use a lambda as the functor in c++11.

Answer (score 0):

auto cmp=[](pair a,pair b){return a.second>b.second;};
priority_queue,vector>,decltype(cmp)> pq(cmp);

this is min heap of pairs by the second element in the pair.